# why the past conditional?

Tags: temps-composés

I’m reading a transcription of an interview with a writer (Alain Fleischer in case anyone is interested). The speaker explains that he postponed writing an autobiographical book until he’d written some fiction, and had thus acquired more experience as a writer.

This passage has been troubling me:

> Je me serais bien gardé de commencer par ce texte autobiographique quand je me suis consacré a l’écriture: pourtant, avec ce souvenir d’adolescence en tête, il eut été facile de faire un premier livre.

I’ve concluded that *il eut été facile de faire un premier livre* should read *il eût été …*, and understand why the plus-que-parfait du subjonctif has been used. (But please comment if you think I’m wrong.)

I remain troubled by:

> Je me serais bien gardé de commencer

I understand the idiom: *he was very careful to avoid starting*. But why the past conditional?

In English, we can say *I would have been about sixteen when …* rather than *I was about sixteen when ….* I’ve been trying to decide what the first usage conveys: uncertainty?; psychological distance?. Would the speaker's use of the past conditional be comparable?

Comment: You are right about the your first statement: that should be *il **eût** été facile...*, i.e. a *plus-que-parfait du subjonctif*.

Comment: "He was very careful to avoid starting..." would rather be "Il fut prudent de ne pas commencer..."

Comment: Just a non-native guess, but since he did [successfully/fortunately] postpone writing *L’Amant en culottes courtes* (his first, in fact only, entirely autobiographical work) until 2006 (20 years after his first novel), I think your “careful to avoid” interpretation is close, but maybe he’s leaving room for doubt as to whether he **successfully avoided it on purpose** or whether he **fortunately avoided it subconsciously**: I **apparently** carefully avoided/ended up by refraining from starting with “L’Amant,” [in spite of how easy it would have been to do so with such memories fresh in mind].”

Comment: @Papa: Thanks again for taking the trouble to do some research on my behalf. I read your response to an earlier past-conditional question, so I've seen that "apparently" interpretation before. Here it perhaps does leave us to guess the speaker's resolution at the time, presumably because the speaker is himself now unsure. But this makes the utterance so (wilfully?) obscure. Nor do these thoughts seem to aligh with Circeus's view.

Comment: @Papa: Since you're "non-native", should I assume that you are a native English speaker? If so, how do you interpret that "I would have been about 16 ..." idiom that I mentioned in my my original post?

Comment: Imo, Circeus’ translation ("I would much rather not have started with") would be fine as long as it doesn’t **require** one to conclude that Fleischer eventually went against his original wish because, in fact, he remained true to it. In English, that translation would strongly **imply** it, but not require it ("I would much rather not have started with an autobiography, **& in fact I didn’t**"), but maybe the French equivalent wouldn’t permit this kind of “surprise twist.” I’m just not sure if Circeus was right in saying that you “don’t get the idiom” (or at least how Fleischer was using it).

Comment: Re:  "I would have been about 16":  You include "about" in both forms, & that inclusion certainly adds a bit of  uncertainty or hedging to them both, but I think you could easily omit "about" in the "I was 16" form, but not so easily in the "I would have been ... 16" one, which leads me to think that the "would have been" version implies greater uncertainty or [need for] reflection. I'm even tempted to add "Hmmm ...", or "Let's see ..." or "Let me think ..." to the "... I would have been about 16" version to further emphasize the uncertainty, whereas I'm not so tempted with "I was {about} 16"

Comment: You thank me for doing some research (& I did, so "You’re welcome!"), but your question clearly stated that: “The speaker explains **that he postponed** writing an autobiographical book until he’d written some fiction” (& not “that he **wished he'd** postponed ...”), so any research I did was just to (successfully) confirm your clear context-setting statement (that he did write some fiction, [from 1986 to 2005](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alain_Fleischer#%C3%89crits) before writing [his 1st/only autobiographical book in 2006](http://books.openedition.org/bibpompidou/1048)=no counterfactual).

Comment: I really like/am intrigued by this question, which is why I keep returning to it looking for new comments and why I’m especially disappointed in my inability to offer anything beyond guesses & comments. You’ve identified either a mistake made by a talented artist (which I don’t think is the case) or (as I believe), as you put it, an obscure (yet correct) use of the past condition to imply something that is hard (for me) to pin down. Regardless of which one you've identified, identifying such things is a mark of a great question, imo. (1 of 2)

Comment: (2 of 2) With that said (& with the nuance between “I would have been/was 16” in mind), my last (I promise) guess would be “[In light of the eventual outcome], It would appear that I was very careful …” to try to imply the same slight nuance (of uncertainty about actually recalling that thought process of 20 years earlier) that exists between “It would appear” and “It appears” in English.

Comment: @Papa: I think your final guess is convincing – especially in the absence of convincing alternatives. If you were to create an answer from that, I’d accept it.

Answer (score 4):

> "I understand the idiom"

No you don't, and that is the source of your confusion.

What that actually translates to is "I would much rather **not** have started with" (or in a less complex French form *j'aurais de loin préféré ne pas commencer*), hence the conditional required here to express a counterfactual wish since they did in fact *not avoid* what they did despite their wishing they had or could have.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I'm more confused now. My dictionary has the following in the entry for "se garder de faire qch": "to be careful not to do something". So I thought "careful not to start" was a safe assumption. And the start of an autobiographical was avoided (for 20 years, says Papa Poule.) So would the counter-factual have been required?

Comment: The counterfactual is the default meaning of a past conditional in French. The construction sounds odds to an English speaker because the same meaning is expressed in English through what is essentially a simple past (applied to the auxiliary verb), e.g. *j'aurais dû m'enfuir*, "I should have run away", *je n'aurais pas pu le faire toute seule* "I couldn't have done it alone". Similarly the classic polite formula "you shouldn't have" translates literally into "vous n'auriez pas dû".

Comment: I understand that counterfactual is the default meaning of the past conditional in French. What I don’t understand is why the past conditional was used when the content of the sentence (he refrained from starting) was factual.

Comment: In this particular case? Because it's a counterfactual _wish_, i.e. another valid translation could be "i wish I hadn't started with this text".

Comment: But he did NOT begin with an autobiography. It still seems to me that you have not understood that.

Answer (score 2):

For the sentence

> Je me serais bien gardé de commencer par ce texte autobiographique quand je me suis consacré a l’écriture [...]

The fact already happened, he did began by his autobiographical book when he began writing. If we just take that fact and nothing else, the *passé composé* would have replaced the *conditionnel passé* and the sentence would have been something like this:

> J'ai commencé par un texte autobiographique quand je me suis consacré
>   à l'écriture [...]

So now for the past conditionnal. Let's take this part here:

> Je me serais bien gardé de [...]

Here the meaning of that part of the sentence, and it is implicit, is that he **regrets** to have begun his writting by an autobiographical book.

Think about it that way: when you regret something, you ask yourself what you could have done to not have regrets. That's hypothetical, as you have no way of knowing the outcome since the action already happened, hence the conditional.

You can see that easily if you use the keyword `Si` to introduce the condition. That also clarifies the condition and makes it explicit:

> Si j'avais pu changer le passé, je me serais bien gardé de commencer
>   par ce texte autobiographique quand je me suis consacré a l’écriture
>   [...]

Since `Si j'avais pu changer le passé` is generic and doesn't add anything to the sentence, you can remove that part and juste have it implicit:

> Je me serais bien gardé de commencer par ce texte autobiographique quand je me suis consacré a l’écriture[...]

**edit to complete with the clarification from justerman in the comments**

If he did not write an autobiographical book and it is true, rather than being hypothetical, the right use for the sentence would have been with the `plus-que-parfait`.

> Je m'étais bien gardé de commencer par ce texte autobiographique quand
>   je me suis consacré a l’écriture[...]

However, if the conclusion (he did not write and autobiographical book) is true, the conditional could still be used if the condition he used was hypothetical.

Example of conditions:

He did not write an autobiographical book because:

1. He was too young (hypothetical, not the real reason)
2. He wasn't experienced (true)

With the same conclusion, you could have the use of both the `plus-que-parfait` and the `conditional`, depending on the condition.

> Je m'étais demandé si j'étais trop jeune. Je me serais bien
>   gardé de commencer par ce texte autobiographique quand je me suis
>   consacré a l’écriture [...]
>
> En réalité, je n'avais pas d'expérience. Je m'étais bien gardé de commencer par ce texte autobiographique quand je me suis consacré a l’écriture [...]

**other edit with the provided source (sentence in question at the 55th paragraph):** http://books.openedition.org/bibpompidou/1048?lang=fr

I will quote a larger block that contains that sentence in question:

> Dans le récit autobiographique, il ne s’agit pas d’explorer l’inconnu,
>   de l’inventer, mais de fouiller dans la mémoire pour retrouver par
>   l’exercice d’écriture ce qui a eu lieu réellement. Ce sont deux
>   positions mentales très différentes, voire opposées. Par contre, il
>   est certain que je n’ai pu écrire ce livre autobiographique que parce
>   que j’étais passé par l’apprentissage de l’écriture romanesque.
>   Paradoxalement, c’est parce que j’ai appris à écrire de la fiction que
>   j’ai pu sans trahir ma mémoire à mes propres yeux, évoquer un épisode
>   précieux de ma vie.
>    **Je me serais bien gardé de commencer par ce texte autobiographique
>   quand je me suis enfin consacré à l’écriture : pourtant, avec ce
>   souvenir d’adolescence en tête, il eut été facile de faire un premier
>   livre.** Je me suis méfié de cette fausse facilité, je sentais que c’eut
>   été un trompe-l’œil sur mon projet d’écrivain et que, par ailleurs, je
>   n’étais pas prêt – presque techniquement… – à traiter ce sujet sans
>   l’abîmer, à restituer les événements, leur contexte, l’époque, dans
>   leurs finesses, leur poésie, leur émotion… C’est alors, par absence de
>   métier, que j’aurais échoué à être fidèle à la mémoire, et à rester
>   dans l’exacte autobiographie.

To summarize that block he gives the reasons why he didn't began with an autobiographical book. What is particular about that particular sentence you highlighted is that he talks about himself as a kid, and not as the "him" of today. The conditional is used in that sentence in that way:

> Si quand j'étais petit, j'avais pensé à écrire un texte
>   autobiographique, je me serais gardé de le faire.

When he was a teen he did not thought about writing the text, but even if he did, he would still not have written the text, because of the reasons mentionned after the highlighted sentence.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I appreciate that you have tried to explain. But he did NOT begin with an autobiography. It seems to me that you have not understood that.

Comment: Yeah you are right sorry, I focused too much on the first part. I've edited my post to cover what you just said. In brief I can't see how "conditional" could be justified if the condition to the conclusion is true and did happen. If the condition was hypothetical, it must have been said earlier or after that sentence, implicitly or explicitly.

Comment: Do you have the transcript or a link where I could read it by chance? It would be really helpful for me to understand the exact situation and not just making assumptions.

Comment: Try this: http://books.openedition.org/bibpompidou/1048?lang=fr

Comment: Thanks you! I've added another edit to my answer. Does that explains well to you the use of the conditional for the sentence?

Comment: You’ve gone to a lot of trouble to help me. Thank you. I already understood the default use of the past conditional: it’s the same as in English. But I didn’t think that default usage could apply in the passage quoted and I was wondering whether others on Stack Exchange could explain it. I don’t think anyone has. I am not convinced by your explanation. I don’t agree that the speaker was expressing his teenage thoughts. Rather they were his thoughts when he decided to become a writer (the time when he resolved to postpone his autobiographical book). Thank you again.